# Datatable how to order by a number with decimals jstl

Tags: sorting, datatable

I work with datables.

In a jsp I have the following field

```
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="4">Averiada En Estacion:&nbsp;<c:out value="${vd.averiada}" /></td>
```

In the screen  the values of this field  are

996,4
996,4 
948,5 
9.917,5 
9.670,8
9.570,9 
819,1
8.944,5

I have in a javascript the definition of datatables for all application

```
$('#' + idTabla).DataTable({
            "language": {
                "decimal": ",",
                "thousands": "."
            },
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: botones,
            "columnDefs": columnDefs,
            "scrollY": scrollSize + 'px',
            'rowsGroup': rowsGroup,
            "scrollCollapse": scrollcollapse,
            "paging": paginacion,
            "searching": searchParam,
            "ordering": orderParam,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "info": infoParam,
            "order":[[columnOrden, tipoOrden]],
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            "scrollX": true,
        });
        $('#' + idTabla).DataTable.render.number(',', '.', 2, '');
```

How can I order this field like number?

Comment: Hard to answer without a description of those values, i.e how they look like and how they should be sorted.

Comment: When I click in the order arrow, values must be order from smallest to greatest and when I click again from greatest to smallest